# setImageDrawable vs setBackground for placeholder

Tags: java, android

I am trying to find the right approach in setting the placeholder image/resource (`VectorDrawable` resource in my case) for an `ImageView` that gets set, with the target image bitmap when it is available.

There are two approaches I saw in guides. I can either set a background using the `background` property on XML or programmatically using `setBackground()`. Then, I would set the target image using `setImageDrawable()`.

The second approach is to use `setImageDrawable()` for the placeholder and later use `setImageDrawable()` again for the target image.

Both approaches work but I have noticed some UI lag when using the first approach. I am not sure if it is caused by the approach or not.

So, I want to know. What is the correct approach in using placeholders and why?

Thank you.

Comment: You should go with the second approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second approach is always the best for this task.
But still, if you want to go with the first approach then the correct way to use it is like this

```
int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    setBackgroundDrawable();
} else {
    setBackground();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, GOVIND DIXIT. Can you explain why it is the best approach, though?

Comment: setBackground is deprecated and It requires API 16. This might help you http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2013/12/setimagedrawable-vs-setimageresource-vs.html

Answer (score 1):

when load image in ImageView changed src value, it's mean not changing background.
change background is expensive for android, It gets worse when we want to load a lot of images (like ListView, RecyclerView, ...).
for having better performance should be changed image src, not changing image background.

for changing image src you can use

```
image.setImageResource()
```

or

```
image.setImageDrawable()
```

change background suitable for a single image

In addition, all image loader support placeholder if using that's the same doesn't need set manually.